# How do I make iClip Lite work in newer versions of Mac OS X?

Tags: copy-paste, dashboard-widget, dashboard

[iClip Lite](https://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/business/icliplite.html) is a Clipboard Manager dashboard widget, which won an Apple Design Award back in 2006. It's pretty great.

Unfortunately, the widget appears to have broken all the way back in Snow Leopard†. You can still save and retrieve clipboard items, but the preview of all those items is invisible. Without a way to see what was saved, the widget is pretty useless.

[image]

Can this be fixed?

---

<sup>† If not earlier—Snow Leopard is just the earliest version of OS X I have access to.</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix the preview!

Right click `iClip lite.wdgt` in Finder and select `Show Package Contents`, then open `js`/`scripts.js` in a text editor.

Go to line 49, which reads:

```
node.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; left: 1.5em; top: 1.5em; width: 7.2em; height: 7.2em;")
```

Change and height to `300px` and `150px`, respectively. Your new line 49 should read:

```
node.setAttribute("style", "position: absolute; left: 1.5em; top: 1.5em; width: 300px; height: 150px;");
```

Save your changes, close the file, and reload the widget (in the Dashboard, click the Widget and enter <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>). Everything should work now.

I tested this on Mavericks and High Sierra, so I assume it will work on the full gamut of Snow Leopard through Mojave.

Comment: As an aside, I wonder how it broke—how did a width and height of `7.2em`, which clearly used to work, suddenly become so far from the correct size? Some arcane change in webkit, I guess?

Comment: I assumed incorrectly—I've been informed the above modification makes the preview too large on Mojave. Oh well, what's important is knowing where the values are.